# Chartjs scatter chart's x axis is heavily padded

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, vue-chartjs

Im working on making a nice chart in vuejs with chartjs. I have a scatter chart here and chartjs seems to want to pad the x axis with unused values when I use large numbers like a unix timestamp.

Here is what it looks like with lables on so you can see what is happening:
[image: padding issue]

I added the prop ...

```
          xAxes: [
        {
          display: true,
          ticks: {
            padding: 0,
        }
```

...assuming that was the solution but it has no affect.

Thank you!

[Codepen of behavior](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/exLVrj)

Comment: Can you post some sample code or a fiddle so we can reproduce this? It's difficult to say what the problem is without being able to actually reproduce it.

Comment: Sure!

Here ya go: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/exLVrj

the spaces on the sides are what I want to get rid of. I think its because it just picks large steps for the xaxis ticks with large numbers.

The first value on my xaxis should be my smallest x value, and the last should be the largest. @AndroidNoobie

Edit: wrong link!

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

Since all of my x values are multiples of 3600 (one hour in seconds) I was able to set the x axis stepSize to 3600 to make sure it begins and ends on a step.

```
    scales: {
      xAxes: [
        {
          ticks: {
            stepSize: 3600
          }
        }
      ],
    }
```