# How can I remove gap before first point in a chart?

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I'm attempting to remove this extra space seen in the picture. I need the x axis to start at the edge of the chart and remove the extra white space. I've attempted to set the x axis offset to false already.
I'm running the latest version of react-chartjs-2 (5.2.0)

[image: Picture of chart in current state.]

here are my current chart options :

```
    export const options = {
  responsive: true,
  interaction: {
    mode: "index" as const,
    intersect: false,
  },
  stacked: true,
  plugins: {
    title: {
      display: false,
      text: "Chart.js Line Chart - Multi Axis",
    },
    legend: {
      display: false,
    },
    annotation: {
      annotations: {
        line1: {
          type: "line",
          yMin: 150.0,
          yMax: 150.0,
          borderColor: "rgb(255, 99, 132)",
          borderWidth: 2,
        },
      },
    },
  },
  scales: {
    y: {
      grid:{
        drawTicks: false,
       },
      type: "linear" as const,
      display: true,
      position: "left" as const,
      stacked: true,
      ticks: {
        color: "#006FAF",
        font: {
          size: 16,
          family: "NimbusSansNovusDRegular",
        },
      },
    },
    x: {
      stacked: true,
      grid: {
        drawTicks: false,
      },
      ticks: {
        color: "#006FAF",
        font: {
          size: 16,
          family: "NimbusSansNovusDRegular",
        },
      },
    },
  },
};

export const months = [
  "January",
  "February",
  "March",
  "April",
  "May",
  "June",
  "July",
  "August",
  "September",
  "October",
  "November",
  "December",
];
```

Comment: Please provide debuggable code (like a forkable stackblitz or codesandbox link), one can't debug partial code. The problem may come from the data, or from the selection of the widget on top, at this point one may only guess, which is not very productive.

Answer (score 0):

you can use x: { offset: false } and clip: { left: 5, top: 5, right: 5, bottom: 5 } on options top level

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is similar to the one referenced in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54689147/chartjs-scatter-charts-x-axis-is-heavily-padded)

Try adding a step size to your xAxes

```html
ticks: {
   stepSize: 3600
}
```

If the X axes labels are too big then try making them vertical or remove them to remove the spacing as well.
Created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/adil_approves/pen/abMGVXv) for your reference